# Is there a way to implement equations as Dymos path constraints?

Tags: optimization, simulation, openmdao

For example, if I have a function h_max(mach) and I want the altitude to always respect this predefined altitude-mach relationship throughout the flight envelop, how could I implement this?

I have tried calculating the limit quantity (in this case, h_max) as its own state and then calculating another state as h_max-h and then constraining that through a path constraint to being greater than 0.

This type of approach has worked, but involved two explicit components, a group and a lot of extra coding just to get a constraint working. I was wondering if there was a better way?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The next version of Dymos, 1.7.0 will be released soon and will support this.

In the mean time, you can install the latest developmental version of Dymos directly from github to have access to this capability:

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos.git
```

Then, you can define boundary and path constraints with an equation.  Note the equation must have an equals sign in it, and then `lower`, `upper`, or `equals` will apply to the result of the equation.

In reality, dymos is just inserting an OpenMDAO ExecComp for you under the hood, so the one caveat to this is that your expression must be compatible with complex-step differentiation.

Here's an example of the brachistochrone that uses constraint *expressions* to set the final `y` value to a specific value while satisfying a path constraint defined with a second equation.

```
import openmdao.api as om
import dymos as dm
from dymos.examples.plotting import plot_results
from dymos.examples.brachistochrone import BrachistochroneODE
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#
# Initialize the Problem and the optimization driver
#
p = om.Problem(model=om.Group())
p.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
p.driver.declare_coloring()

#
# Create a trajectory and add a phase to it
#
traj = p.model.add_subsystem('traj', dm.Trajectory())

phase = traj.add_phase('phase0',
                       dm.Phase(ode_class=BrachistochroneODE,
                                transcription=dm.GaussLobatto(num_segments=10)))

#
# Set the variables
#
phase.set_time_options(fix_initial=True, duration_bounds=(.5, 10))

phase.add_state('x', fix_initial=True, fix_final=True)

phase.add_state('y', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False)

phase.add_state('v', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False)

phase.add_control('theta', continuity=True, rate_continuity=True,
                  units='deg', lower=0.01, upper=179.9)

phase.add_parameter('g', units='m/s**2', val=9.80665)

Y_FINAL = 5.0
Y_MIN = 5.0
phase.add_boundary_constraint(f'bcf_y = y - {Y_FINAL}', loc='final', equals=0.0)
phase.add_path_constraint(f'path_y = y - {Y_MIN}', lower=0.0)

#
# Minimize time at the end of the phase
#
phase.add_objective('time', loc='final', scaler=10)

p.model.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver()

#
# Setup the Problem
#
p.setup()

#
# Set the initial values
#
p['traj.phase0.t_initial'] = 0.0
p['traj.phase0.t_duration'] = 2.0

p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:x', phase.interp('x', ys=[0, 10]))
p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:y', phase.interp('y', ys=[10, 5]))
p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:v', phase.interp('v', ys=[0, 9.9]))
p.set_val('traj.phase0.controls:theta', phase.interp('theta', ys=[5, 100.5]))

#
# Solve for the optimal trajectory
#
dm.run_problem(p)

# Check the results
print('final time')
print(p.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.time')[-1])

p.list_problem_vars()
```

Note the constraints from the `list_problem_vars()` call that come from `timeseries_exec_comp` - this is the OpenMDAO ExecComp that Dymos automatically inserts for you.

```
--- Constraint Report [traj] ---
    --- phase0 ---
        [final]   0.0000e+00 == bcf_y [None]
        [path]    0.0000e+00 <= path_y  [None]

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/openmdao/recorders/sqlite_recorder.py:227: UserWarning:The existing case recorder file, dymos_solution.db, is being overwritten.
Model viewer data has already been recorded for Driver.
Full total jacobian was computed 3 times, taking 0.057485 seconds.
Total jacobian shape: (71, 51) 


Jacobian shape: (71, 51)  (12.51% nonzero)
FWD solves: 12   REV solves: 0
Total colors vs. total size: 12 vs 51  (76.5% improvement)

Sparsity computed using tolerance: 1e-25
Time to compute sparsity: 0.057485 sec.
Time to compute coloring: 0.054118 sec.
Memory to compute coloring: 0.000000 MB.
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/openmdao/core/total_jac.py:1585: DerivativesWarning:Constraints or objectives [('traj.phases.phase0.timeseries.timeseries_exec_comp.path_y', inds=[(0, 0)])] cannot be impacted by the design variables of the problem.
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: [18.02999766]
            Iterations: 14
            Function evaluations: 14
            Gradient evaluations: 14
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
final time
[1.80299977]
----------------
Design Variables
----------------
name                        val             size  indices                                        
--------------------------  --------------  ----  --------------------------------------------- 
traj.phase0.t_duration      [1.80299977]    1     None                                           
traj.phase0.states:x        |12.14992234|   9     [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]                            
traj.phase0.states:y        |22.69124774|   10    [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]                
traj.phase0.states:v        |24.46289861|   10    [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]                
traj.phase0.controls:theta  |266.48489386|  21    [ 0  1  2  3  4  5   ... 4 15 16 17 18 19 20]  

-----------
Constraints
-----------
name                                                         val            size  indices                                        alias                                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------  -------------  ----  ---------------------------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------- 
timeseries.timeseries_exec_comp.bcf_y                        [0.]           1     [29]                                           traj.phases.phase0->final_boundary_constraint->bcf_y  
timeseries.timeseries_exec_comp.path_y                       |15.73297378|  30    [ 0  1  2  3  4  5   ... 3 24 25 26 27 28 29]  traj.phases.phase0->path_constraint->path_y           
traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:x                 |6e-08|        10    None                                           None                                                  
traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:y                 |7e-08|        10    None                                           None                                                  
traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:v                 |3e-08|        10    None                                           None                                                  
traj.phase0.continuity_comp.defect_control_rates:theta_rate  |0.0|          9     None                                           None                                                  

----------
Objectives
----------
name           val            size  indices  
-------------  -------------  ----  ------- 
traj.phase0.t  [18.02999766]  1     -1
```

Comment: Hi Rob,

Thanks so much for your answer and for implementing this feature. I would rather upgrade straight to a non-dev version, seeing as I am not much of a python expert. Do you know when this feature will likely be included in a standard rollout? Thanks.

Comment: We're trying to get 1.7.0 out soon, hopefully the next few days but probably next week at the latest.

Comment: Hi Rob, this is a late answer but I wanted to thank you for answering me so quickly.